# using Spring integration with spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

I have a spring batch application which reads from file , does some processing and finally write a customized output. This all happens in one step. In next step i have a tasklet which archives the input files (move to another folder). This application works fine.But, now i got a requirement to sftp output files on a remote servers where they would further processed. I got a way to sftp using spring integration where i have created a input channel which feeds to outboundchannel adapter. I put my files as payload in message and send messages to channel. The only problem i see here is that everytime I have to get the context i eed to load the spring config file, which seems kind of hackish way to do the task. Does anyone know about any way to integrate SI with SB.

Let me know if you want to see my config...
Thanks in Advance !!

code to access the same app-context without loading the spring config again

```
public class AppContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware{

    private static ApplicationContext ctx;

    public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return ctx;
    }

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext appContext) throws BeansException {
        ctx = appContext;
    }
}
```

code to push the output file to sftp server

```
log.info("Starting transfer of outputFile : " + absoluteOutputFileName);
final File file = new File(absoluteOutputFileName);
final Message<File> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(file).build();
AppContextProvider context = new AppContextProvider();
final MessageChannel inputChannel = context.getApplicationContext().getBean("toChannel",MessageChannel.class);
inputChannel.send(message);
log.info("transfer complete for : " + absoluteOutputFileName);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the `spring-batch-integration` module within the Spring Batch project.  In there, we have components for launching jobs via messages.  In your situation, you'd FTP the file down then have the `JobLaunchingMessageHandler` launch the job.

You can also watch this video of a talk I co-presented at SpringOne a couple years ago on this topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8tiqeV07XlI

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will go through it, In the mean time i found a way to get the same app-context of my application . Please suggest if it is right way to go for it or if you see any issues with this. added the code in my original question

Comment: Why are you creating an ApplicationContext per job you run?

Comment: I am not creating ApplicationContext per job. I load the spring config once and then for each file i invoke the job one by one .(i am checking i\p folder for available files and running a loop)

Answer (score 0):

As Michael said, you'll definitely want to look at and leverage `spring-batch-integration`. We actually use Spring Integration as a wrapper of sorts to launch 100% of our Spring Batch jobs.

One use case we've found particularly useful is leveraging the `spring-integration-file` Inbound Channel Adapters to poll staging directories to indicate when a new batch file has landed. As the poller finds a new file, we then launch a new batch job using the input filename as a parameter.

This has been a real help when it comes to restartability, because we now have one job instance per file as opposed to having a job kick off at arbitrary intervals and then partition across however many files happen to be in the staging folder. Now if an exception occurs during processing, you can target a specific job for restart immediately rather than waiting for 99 of the 100 "good" files to finish first.

Comment: @ Dean Can you share the code which you used to invoke your job through SI ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's proprietary at this point, but we are actually in the process of cleaning up a couple project-specific portions of the code so we can share it with the community.... hopefully within a couple months.